# change Logging level on run time with @RefreshScope

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

We are looking for log level change on runtime by updating the log level in the `application-env.yml` file. We are not allowed to use any endpoint/URL on the various higher environment so we can't leverage the spring actuator's provided functionality to change log level on runtime.
We believe that there should be something which can be combined with `@RefreshScope` of spring cloud and which allows us to just make changes in property/yml file and it will be get reflected on runtime.

Comment: How would you trigger it without actuator?

Comment: we do not want to trigger anything manually, it would be reflected as i just change log level in property file as we can achieve it for some configuration properties with @RefreshScope, I am looking for similar kind of functionality

Comment: so, polling for changes in the property file. We currently do not support this.

Comment: @spencergibb, Do we have similar or same kind of feature in pipeline for upcoming release?

Comment: Possibly, I'll have to look and see

Comment: @spencergibb thank you for your support and time but eager to know about the same kind of feature i.e.. feature number or something on github